# is it possible to read data as a stream with athena-express node package?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I want to download all the data from a table as CSV, stored in Athena. I need data fetched from Athena as a stream so I don't run into out of memory issue

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it currently supports this in a simple way unfortunately.

Instead, you may need to set the boolean flag to return results to false (so it doesn't return the results), and use the path it returns to where where Athena results are stored, and create an S3 read stream to that file.